# Require code to perform this loop in SPSS including looping variable names

Tags: loops, variables, spss

I am looking for the spss code to perform the following:
I have three variables: ResponseID and Q1 and Q2 that needs to be copied throughout my data set, I have already included variables for them - it starts with VAR00002, VAR00003 and VAR00004 several times throughout my data set. I now want to populate them, I therefore have to include the name of the variable in the loop and it needs to carry on doing this for the first set of three, the second set (VAR00005,VAR00006 and VAR00007) etc. (depending on the condition included in the Do IF). Then there is also the Else IF (and another Do If) included afterwards.

```
Loop # = 1 to 27

Do IF (Q[#(23)+2]=2).
COMPUTE (VAR0000(#+1))=ResponseID.
COMPUTE (VAR0000(#+2))=Q1.
COMPUTE (VAR0000(#+3))=Q2.
End if.

Else If.

Do If.
Q[(#-1)*(23)+3])=2.
DELETE VARIABLES Q[#(23)+3] TO Q623.
End If.

End Else If.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need to do, but take a look at DO REPEAT, which allows you to repeat a set of transformations in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Niether I understand exactly what you are trying to do, perhaps look into [`LOOP / VECTOR`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_vector_examples.htm?lang=en) combination